# How to get mulitple on focus changed listener events to fire

Tags: android, text, edit

I have 4 edit text boxes that will automatically calculate the difference of the entered number. Then will display the answer to a edit text box. My problem is that the first event works fine. But I am unable to determine why the second through fourth events will not execute. Each edit text box should work independently of each other. Meaning, edit text 1 once focus is lost, will run the calculation and stop. When edit text 2 has lost focus, then the calculation will run and stop. Is there a way to get this to work?

Here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.premix);

    final EditText vw3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final EditText vw7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    vw3.setOnFocusChangeListener(this); 
    vw7.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);


}
}

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
    if ((v.getId() == R.id.editText3) && (hasFocus==false)){

    EditText vw3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    EditText vw2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    float f1=0;
    float f5=0;                                                             
    f1=Float.parseFloat(vw3.getText().toString());
    f5=(f1-100)*-1;
    String str1 = String.valueOf(df2.format(f5));
    vw2.setText(str1);

        }

if  ((v.getId() == R.id.editText7) && (hasFocus==false)){

    EditText vw7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    EditText vw8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    float f2=0;
    float f6=0;                                                             
    f2=Float.parseFloat(vw7.getText().toString());
    f6=(f2-100)*-1;
    String str2 = String.valueOf(df2.format(f6));
    vw8.setText(str2);
     } 
 }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many days of trial and error and I found the solution!

On the OnCreate section you will need to set your views

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.premix);

EditText vw3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
EditText vw7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
vw3.setOnFocusChangeListener(this); 
vw7.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);


}
```

Now you listen for the focus change by doing this.

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

if((v.getId() == R.id.editText7) && (hasFocus == false))
    calc1();     

if((v.getId() == R.id.editText10) && (hasFocus == false))
     calc2();
```

then separate the individual logic and provide a public void for the calculations.

```
public void calc1(){  
//do something here
}

public void calc2(){
//do something here
}
```

The result of doing this is that the different edit text will act independent of each other.

Addition: 
If you're doing this in a custom ViewGroup you need to implement View.OnFocusChangeListener.